# How is “account” different with “theory”, “model” or “approach”?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, terminology, philosophy

For example, this article about [Personal Autonomy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/personal-autonomy/#FourLessOverAccoPersAuto) is talking about "Four More or Less Overlapping Accounts of Personal Autonomy". I understand that "account" here can be substituted with:

- approach
- explanation
- model
- theory
- consideration
- perspective

However, I don't know when to use "account" instead of the others. Plus that the closest meaning of [account](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account) in this context would be: "a written or spoken description of an event". Still, I find it's still quite far from "approach".

<sub>[I reask this question on Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/78554/19487).</sub>

<sub>A comment from the meta [Why are questions about the usage of synonyms off-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14907/why-are-questions-about-the-usage-of-synonyms-off-topic?cb=1#comment59841_14908) regarding the closure of this post, which I agree: "Yes, the OP could have produced a lengthy question, cluttered with vague definitions from general-purpose dictionaries, just to prove that they have been 'looked up', but that would have only confirmed what both the OP and most of the rest of us can be assumed to already know: the meanings of these words are close and overlapping. The question made it obvious that the OP was seeking an explanation of the nuances that go beyond that, from those who have greater experience with the actual use of these words."</sub>

Comment: An ~_approach_ and a _perspective_ are ways of looking at the subject.

Comment: @Xanne Story? I read the article and it doesn't resemble that. Plus that the closest meaning of [account](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account "ACCOUNT | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary") in this context would be: "a written or spoken description of an event". Still, I find it's still quite far from either "story" or "approach".

Comment: The author actually refers to 'one story' and 'another story'! Presumably they mean 'one way of describing what happens'.

Comment: @KateBunting hmm, but in other articles no story is mentioned, yet the word "account" is still used

Comment: can you help me migrate this to [philosophy.se]?

Comment: "Account", in this context, basically means "description".

Comment: The author of your article uses the descriptors 'account' and 'story' interchangeably, but from the way they are using them I'd say 'school of thought' / 'model' is intended. I'd use 'approach'.

Comment: Why do you want this migrated to philosophy.se? You have accepted an answer and the community has deemed the question as on topic here.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен yes I have accepted an answer. However it says that the usage is not common, while I feel that it's actually common within the philosophy circle. Because of that mismatch, I think migrating the question to there will reveal more subtle things that most folks in this site may not be aware of. Just my thought; I'm not really sure

Comment: @Ooker I think migrating it kind of pooh-poohs the work done by people here. I recommend asking a question at philosophy, pointing to this one, explaining how you need a more nuanced answer.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен [Dismissing the people here as unworthy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooh-pooh "Pooh-pooh - Wikipedia") I'm not sure how that would be?

Comment: Because the question would be closed because the work they have done is not acceptable, i.e. our experts here have worked to answer your question and you think their answers are not good enough. That's why you're asking for the migration, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен well yes, but not as an intention to be disrespectful. Changing the accept tick to another answer is also a kind of saying the old accepted answer is not good enough. Plus that I see this kind of migration in many sites as well?

Comment: The question as posed here is on topic. Closing, and moreover migrating, an on topic question is not within the guidelines for closing. I still recommend re-asking the question on phil.se. I acknowledge that cross-posting is not allowed, but your second question will be different from this one as it will be asking about philosophy to philosophers, not about English to Englishers.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I open a meta question for this, I hope it's on your concern: [Is it good to migrate questions which are on-topic and have answers?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14889/80007)

Comment: I’m can voting to close this question. A dictionary offers different synonyms of a word, because each applies differently. If one fits where others don't, what is the problem?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I suppose asking on when to use a a synonym is fine? I have seen many questions like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is using the following sense of 'account', given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/account):

> **account** ... 5. [countable noun] [usually NOUN of noun, oft poss NOUN]
>
> An account of something is a theory which is intended to explain or
> describe it. [formal]
>
> - *This basic utilitarian model gives a relatively unsophisticated account of human behaviour.*
> - *Science, on Weber's account, is an essentially value-free activity*.

Note that four theories are put forward by the author of the article, Sarah Buss; the first is introduced *According to one prominent **conception**,*

This is not a common usage, and would be better replaced by 'model' or 'theory'.

Answer (score 0):

From the context, it looks like the author used the "a statement explaining one's conduct" meaning from [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account).

Comment: I disagree. This (M-W sense 2a) is the 'Explain yourself!' ('He was asked to give an account of himself/his recent behaviour') sense.

Comment: You are right, @EdwinAshworth; I want to change my answer to 2b, not 2a. I glossed over the differences between them...I was on my phone which is not great for context..